# PIR transistor ,minimal circuit, minimum current,

Tags: transistors, sensor

We would like to take a PIR transistor (not a module) , and use it to detect a human body in a distance of 20cm only .

The thing is, we don't want to use an amplifier ,  we want the current under 100uA.

So i am looking for some configuration where putting this transistor together with some resistors divider, to produce high logic on a human presence within 20cm .

I couldn't find anything but the modules -`HC-SR501` .

Could someone give me something to start with , some minimal configuration to start and read data ?

thanks .

Comment: Are you assuming that you cannot use an amplifier since you want less than 100uA current consumption ? Have you looked for any amplifiers that use less than 100 uA ? Ahum, TLC271 in low bias mode: 33uA max. And that opamp is ancient, for sure there are even better ones.

Comment: How will you be able to tell it isn't a bear of the approximate same dimensions as a human or maybe a cat at half the distance?

Comment: The product will have a button with the text: "If you're human, press here" ;-)

Comment: PIR sensors  use pyroelectric transducers as detectors, which provide a momentary output voltage which is positive when they're heated above their ambient temperature and negative when they're cooled.  As such, they're only able to detect a moving target, which means that if your target is stationary, or slow moving,  the transducer won't see anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Dave said, raw PIR sensor won't be very useful for you. The modules contain a small IC which do the processing for you. They perform the calculations on the output generated by raw PIR sensor and give you a HIGH or LOW depending upon whether motion is being sensed or not. See the image below. There is a chip BISS0001 which does that for you:

[image: PIR sensor]

Trying to achieve that using a raw sensor and basic circuit will be difficult and not at all power saving.

Panasonic manufactures passive PIR sensor modules which draw very low current. WL series consumes 1-6 uA during standby and 100 uA while detecting and should be suitable for your job. These are compact as compared to the general PIR sensors that you find on hobby electronics websites. Here is an image:

[image: PaPIR]

On a flip side, you won't have features like sensitivity and delay adjustment. You need to take care of those things using a micro-controller. Well, can't have everything at once...

Refer to this website for datasheets and more details:

http://na.industrial.panasonic.com/products/sensors/sensors-automotive-industrial-applications/pir-motion-sensor-papirs

Comment: they seems great to our needs, but is there something more popular ? you cant find them almost nowhere , they are very expensive for mass production . What should i look for to find alternatives ?

Comment: Try looking for "Low power PIR" on google. You will find some useful links. I found an item - SB0072 but it doesn't have a well prepared datasheet. Still, it claims current draw < 50uA. Besides this, you can get better price by finding better vendors. If you are planning for bulk, you might be able to get panasonic sensors for around 4 USD if you happen to find a good vendor.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a PIR sensor is not a transistor, although the packaging may be similar in some cases.

Secondly, the output of a PIR sensor is an AC signal, based on the *changes* in thermal energy it is receiving, not its absolute value. These changes are enhanced by using optics (usually a Fresnel lens of some sort) to project multiple "zones" onto the sensor, and the output signal is caused by a warm body entering and leaving those zones. For this reason, a PIR sensor is not really all that good at detecting nearby warm objects that cover multiple zones at once.

If you want to detect "warm" bodies at close range, you'll need something a lot more sophisticated than a bare PIR sensor. For example, look into the technology used to automatically flush toilets, etc. — they run for a long time on low current.

Comment: I am not sure what you saying, i think 99% of all security systems, are using PIR sensors, where their ultimate goal is to detect that someone is standing near a window or a door . isn't it? so how are they "not good" for detecting a human body ?

Comment: No, a PIR sensor is best at detecting someone crossing an open area such as a hallway or a room. Or even outdoors, where it can be used to activate a light. A PIR sensor cannot "see" through a door or a window (glass is not transparent to long-wave IR radiation).

Comment: @DaveTweed: Soda-lime float glass, which is what most windows are made from, has a decent spectral response out to about 2750 nanometers, which will enable a PIR sensor looking through a window to respond to the changes in its field of view which disrupt its resting state. Check [**this**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soda-lime_glass) out.